# Beta distribution with bounds at [0.1, 0.5]

Tags: python, scipy, beta-distribution

I'd like to construct a beta distribution where the mu and sigma are 0.28 and 0.003, respectively, and the distribution is bound at [0.1, 0.5].

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from scipy import stats

mu = 0.28
stdev = 0.003

lb = 0.1
ub = 0.5

def calc_alpha(x, y):
    res = x * ((x*(1-x) / y**2)-1)
    return res

def calc_beta(x, y):
    res = (1 - x) * ((x*(1-x) / y**2)-1)
    return res

alpha_ = calc_alpha(mu, stdev)
beta_ = calc_beta(mu, stdev)

x = np.linspace(lb, ub, 100000)
y = stats.beta(alpha_, beta_, loc = lb, scale = ub).pdf(x)

fig = px.line(x=x, y=y)
fig.show()
```

This seems to work.  However, as a test, I sample from the same distribution, and I calculate the mean and standard deviation of the sample and get different values than what I started out with.

Also, the min and max of these values isn't the range I want, so pretty sure that I'm not using loc and scale correctly.

```
beta_rands = stats.beta(alpha_, beta_, loc = lb, scale = ub).rvs(1000000)

# 0.24
beta_rands.mean()

# 0.0014
beta_rands.std()

#0.232
beta_rands.min()

#0.247
beta_rands.max()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the linear transformation underlying the `loc` and `scale` parameters.

Let `v1` and `v2` be random variables corresponding to `beta(a=a, b=b)` and `beta(a=a, b=b, loc=loc, scale=scale)` respectively. Then `v1` is transformed into `v2 = loc + v1 * scale`. Since `v1` is in [0, 1], `v2` is in [`loc`, `loc + scale`]. (See notes in [the official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html).)

You want `v2` to be in [0.1, 0.5], so `loc` and `scale` should be 0.1 and 0.4 respectively.

You want the mean and standard deviation of `v2` to be 0.28 and 0.003 respectively, so the mean and standard deviation of `v1` should be (0.28-0.1)/0.4 and 0.003/0.4 respectively, because `v1 = (v2 - 0.1) / 0.4`.(A shift does not change the standard deviation. See [the properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties) of the standard deviation.)

The following example shows the implementation.

```
import scipy.stats

def get_ab(mean, var):
    assert(var < mean*(1-mean))
    var = (mean*(1-mean)/var - 1)
    return mean*var, (1-mean)*var

# v2 = 0.1 + v1 * 0.4
# v1 = (v2 - 0.1) / 0.4
a, b = get_ab((0.28-0.1)/0.4, (0.003/0.4)**2)
rv = scipy.stats.beta(a=a, b=b, loc=0.1, scale=0.4)
print([rv.mean(), rv.std()])
# This will output '[0.28, 0.003]'.
```

Comment: The standard deviation only gets transformed by the scale because it's position doesn't move?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Identities_and_mathematical_properties).

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring a bit, so that the original values can be passed directly to the helper:

```
import scipy.stats

def bound_beta(low, high, mu, sigma):
    """Generate a beta function on low <= x <= high
    with the specified mean and standard deviation."""
    scale = high - low
    mean = (mu - low) / scale
    var = (sigma / scale) ** 2
    assert var < mean * (1 - mean)
    var = mean * (1-mean) / var - 1
    return scipy.stats.beta(mean*var, (1-mean)*var, loc=low, scale=scale)

rv = bound_beta(lb, ub, mu, stdev)
print([rv.mean(), rv.std()])
```